# Override css styles for a single element

Tags: html, css

For `ol, ul, li` in the project I have`list-style: none`.

But in one place I need to specify the marking for the list. How can I do it?

I do so

```
<ul style="list-style: disk; !important">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

But it's not working

Comment: The `!important` should go [_immediately after_](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) the value (before the `;` in this case). That being said, I wouldn't take this approach; I would create a new class specifically for this element.

Comment: Two typos to fix, 1. put `;` at the end, 2. `disc` not `disk`.

Comment: `<ul style="list-style: disc !important;">` It's still not working

Comment: That means you previously declare it on li elements in the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be corrected as below,

```
<ul>
  <li style="list-style: disc !important">...</li>
  <li style="list-style: disc !important">...</li>
  <li style="list-style: disc !important">...</li>
</ul>
```

1. !important is a part of the CSS rule. So it should be placed before
   ";"
2. list-style should applied to the li element, not to ul

Comment: Why is `important` necessary here?

Comment: because if you have something like `li {list-style: none !important}` in your style sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Only changing the `;` will not work, as you can see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeGGaN)

You need to specify the CSS for `li` elements:

```
.disc { list-style: disc; }

<ul>
    <li class="disc">1</li>
    <li class="disc">2</li>
    <li class="disc">3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define a class for use on `ul` which sets the desired style on the `li` elements. Simply setting the `list-style` on the `ul` element's `style` attribute will not work, even if `!important`, because the higher-level definitions for `li` will take precedence. Remember that `!important` does **not** mean that child elements inherit the property "more strongly".

```
.disc li { list-style: disc; }

<ul class="disc">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

This approach will avoid having to set the `list-style` on each individual `li` element.